# I get this message when I try to install software in the Software Center Ubuntu 12.10. No fixes I saw here helped

Tags: installation, software-center, authentication

> Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication
>   service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed:
>   ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.168'}):
>   org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages

Comment: I think it would help pointing to the fixes that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have `aptdaemon` installed properly by running on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aptdaemon aptdaemon-data
```

After this, please try again. This is just a guessing, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your proxy settings are what they should be. I had this issue because my proxy config was wrong.

See my answer to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/272225/143254).