# WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated. `apt-key update` doesn't work

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install bitcoind by simply doing `sudo apt-get install bitcoind`, but I get this error saying that the following packages could not be authenticated:

```
libdb5.1++ libcrypto++9 bitcoind
```

I can simply install them without authenticating them, but since this program may handle money, I would like them to be the correct ones. So I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/75575/133190) here on AskUbuntu, which suggests to do the following:

```
$ sudo apt-key update
$ sudo apt-get update
```

After the first command, it lists four keys of which it says that all remain unchanged. The second command simply does the usual, but it ends with a message saying that there was a GPG-error. After some blabla, it then says that the following signatures are invalid (freely translated from Dutch):

```
BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

And the following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available:

```
NO_PUBKEY 1F968B3903D886E7
```

And the following sugnatures were invalid:

```
BADSIG E585066A30C18A2B Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2013 <packager@opera.com>
```

And that getting stuff from the following address has failed:

```
 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
```

Does anybody know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-key update && sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPG ERROR NO\_PUBKEY : WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520828/gpg-error-no-pubkey-warning-the-following-packages-cannot-be-authenticated)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to add the pub key manually.

The command is

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com «key number»
```

where «key number» you must replace it with the missing key.

For example in this error you received

```
NO_PUBKEY 1F968B3903D886E7
```

you can do

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 1F968B3903D886E7
sudo apt-get update
```

That way you will download this key in your keyring from the keyserver (keyserver.ubuntu.com)

About the BADSIG error, check this [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/64544/95393)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that only solves the NO_PUBKEY, but not the BADSIGs. Any idea how I could solve those?

Comment: Answer edited. Check the link I gave.

Comment: I added a `ppa` from launchpad and this helped me to import their key (ubuntu's keyserver was fine!) to get rid of the 'not authenticated package' when installing. Not sure why this answer is downvoted ;_;

Answer (score 1):

Not the direct answer maybe, but there is a need to update the program:
`update-manager-core` .
If any users are getting the error that packages cannot be authenticated when running **update manager**, then updating this program also updates `update manager`and provides a really quick answer.

BTW, I used **synaptic** to do this update, if that is any help. Once the update processed, then update manager worked as it normally does.

see 1204_HWE_EOL in Ubuntu wiki