# GPG ERROR NO_PUBKEY : WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-sources, gnupg

I have just stared to receive some strange errors regarding GPG keys. Namely I have just added `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and wanted to update and after that I got this:

```
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 030561BEDD45F6C3
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

I have tried to resolved it in 2 ways (provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey))

```
for key in 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A040830F7FAC5991 030561BEDD45F6C3 16126D3A3E5C1192  ; do sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $key ; done
```

but that didn't help (the same errors kept coming with the same keys) so I have tried to do this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

but I got this which opened my eyes:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  launchpad-getkeys libvte-common libvte9 python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-oauth python-secretstorage
  python-simplejson python-vte python-wadllib xclip yad
Suggested packages:
  python-gdata python-keyczar python-kde4 python-testresources
  python-secretstorage-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  launchpad-getkeys libvte-common libvte9 python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-oauth python-secretstorage
  python-simplejson python-vte python-wadllib xclip y-ppa-manager yad
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 915 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,515 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libvte-common libvte9 python-keyring python-lazr.uri python-simplejson
  python-wadllib python-oauth python-lazr.restfulclient python-launchpadlib
  python-secretstorage python-vte xclip
Install these packages without verification? [y/N]
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <KEY>` . For example `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5`

Comment: I tried and this didn't work at that point. Check my answer.

Comment: This is essentially a bug report where you describe a problem and as an answer you refer to the bug report. The bug report itself is for 13.10 which is beyond end of life. If you are on 13.10 I suggest you upgrade. If you are on a current version of Ubuntu I suggest you file a new bug report as the old one is out dated. reference the old one in the new.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: Also [Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository)

Answer (score 59):

Run command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For every 16-character key  that is reported as missing, run the following with the key substituted:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABCDEFGH12345678
```

Comment: I get the following errors: `gpgkeys: key 1DB8ADC1CFCA9579 can't be retrieved`. `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` What can I do?

Comment: what if there were no missing keys reported on apt-get update?