# Unable to run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' due to authentication issues (Plesk repository)

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I've just attempted to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on my Ubuntu 
box, but am getting the following error...

`WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  librdbmspp php5-ioncube-loader sw-libboost-date-time1.49.0 sw-libboost-system1.49.0 sw-libboost-filesystem1.49.0 sw-libboost-program-options1.49.0 sw-libboost-regex1.49.0 sw-libboost-serialization1.49.0 sw-libpoco`

I've tried running...

`$ sudo apt-key update
$ sudo apt-get update`

... as found in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository#answer-75575), but I'm still getting the error.

Can anyone help, please?

### Update on 5th June

Repos currently in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA_11.5.30 precise all
deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/debian/SITEBUILDER_11.5.10 all all
deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/debian/BILLING_11.5.30 all all
```

apt-get:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-63 linux-headers-3.2.0-63-generic
  linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  iproute libgnutls-dev libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgnutls26:i386
  libgnutlsxx27 librdbmspp libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic openssl
  php5-ioncube-loader sw-libboost-date-time1.49.0 sw-libboost-filesystem1.49.0
  sw-libboost-program-options1.49.0 sw-libboost-regex1.49.0
  sw-libboost-serialization1.49.0 sw-libboost-system1.49.0 sw-libpoco
23 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 63.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 217 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  librdbmspp php5-ioncube-loader sw-libboost-date-time1.49.0
  sw-libboost-system1.49.0 sw-libboost-filesystem1.49.0
  sw-libboost-program-options1.49.0 sw-libboost-regex1.49.0
  sw-libboost-serialization1.49.0 sw-libpoco
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

apt-cache policy librdbmspp:

```
# apt-cache policy librdbmspp
librdbmspp:
  Installed: 2.0-735641.13060715
  Candidate: 2.0-735641.13073116
  Version table:
     2.0-735641.13073116 0
        500 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA_11.5.30/ precise/all amd64 Packages
 *** 2.0-735641.13060715 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What are the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Nattgew - Repo details added

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure -a` as root (it may be `dpkg --reconfigure -a`)

Comment: Can you post the full output from `apt-get`? The output you posted is just a "harmless" warning (either because Plesk packages are not signed, or because you do not have the key). There must be another reason apt-get is failing.

Comment: @MarcoScannadinari - When I run `dpkg-reconfigure -a` I get various  `Package 'xxx' is not installed and no info is available.` errors (one at a time, but have installed one that was missing, & now getting another).

Comment: @bain Full contents of the output can be seen here... http://pastebin.com/sEtBK8fn

Comment: I see you have Plesk, there is some bug with it that results in unauthenticated packages (possibly they do not sign their packages), see [this thread](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?287898-Clean-instalation-of-Plesk-11-5).

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy librdbmspp`?

Comment: @bain - output of `apt-cache policy librdbmspp` added.  I couldn't spot anything I understood as linked to this issue in the thread you linked to (sorry, fairly inexperienced with package control). Thanks for you help so far though.

Comment: The output shows that package comes from Plesk. I would bet the rest of the ones that are unauthenticated do too. So I wouldn't worry about it, it is Plesk's problem, just say "y" to `Install these packages without verification [y/N]?` and it will do the upgrade.

Comment: You might want to ask on the Plesk forum and/or report it as a bug to them. You are not the first person here to run into this issue of the Plesk packages not being authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bain.  Will check the packages are all Plesk ones & install anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
# apt-cache policy librdbmspp
librdbmspp:
  Installed: 2.0-735641.13060715
  Candidate: 2.0-735641.13073116
  Version table:
     2.0-735641.13073116 0
        500 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA_11.5.30/ precise/all amd64 Packages
 *** 2.0-735641.13060715 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output shows that package comes from Plesk. I would bet the rest of the ones that are unauthenticated do too. So I wouldn't worry about it, it is Plesk's problem, just say "y" to *"Install these packages without verification [y/N]?"* and it will do the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?297194-Cant-update-11-5-30-on-Ubuntu-bind9-fail! shows that this issue can be caused by AppArmor not being disabled.

From http://kb.parallels.com/112903:

**Symptoms**

AppArmor is a security tool that uses name-based mandatory access controls to restrict or confine the system access of “at risk” applications. AppArmor is not supported by Parallels Plesk Panel. Sometimes AppArmor can interfere with Plesk installation or functionality.

**Resolution**

Disable AppArmor using the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
/etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
```

Comment: AppArmour is not installed on our server