# warning: the following packages cannot be authenticated!

Tags: apt, package-management, juju, repository

I am trying a local installation of the juju charms.

1. Deply charm on machine1
2. copy deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archive` to `/root/test` on machine2
3. Modify the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `/root/test`
4. `apt-get update`
5. When I try to deploy the charm on the machine2, I get the following error:

   ```
   warning: the following packages cannot be authenticated!
   ```

I did the search on error and tried few tricks like `apt-key update` but it did not work. How to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository)

Comment: Which command exactly leads to the error message in step 5?

Comment: @David, I tried also the same search which appeared as google relevant suggestions. I tried few answers mentioned as part of search result. but none worked.
When I deploy mysql, rabbitmq-server, some of the packages python-chardet-whl are being installed. If I install python-chardet-whl on command prompt with the option --force--yes, the package is installed. But if I try the installation without --force-yes option it fails

Comment: Should I change the question to soething relevant like this - Can debian packages from one machine can be installed on another?

Comment: Maybe… I'm not sure. You should definitely include a reference to the linked question in your question with a statement, that you tried all its answers unsuccessfully. You should also clarify, which command(s) lead(s) to the error message in your step 5.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `--force-yes` option when you do the `apt-get install`. It worked for me.