# getting error on command sudo apt-get update when trying to update npm version

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

i am getting error after using this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

errors i am getting on `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu utopic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Try `apt-key update` and `apt-get update` to update authentication keys. Answer from [Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository)

Comment: @MarkKirby i am using 16.04

Comment: No, not really @OwenHines. The problem is all the PPAs mentioned in the error message have nothing for xenial (assuming that's the OP's version based on the last added PPA).

Comment: @MohanGopi - You need to remove all the PPAs mentioned in the error message. They aren't for 16.04 hence the errors.

Comment: @CelticWarrior i am new to ubuntu where should i look for to remove this ppa

Comment: System Settings > Sofware Properties. Open the "other software" tab, find the offending PPAs, select and remove one at a time.

Comment: Oh okay @CelticWarrior